# Silence warning "Could not create compact unwind for [symbol]: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, clang, watchos

Working on a WatchOS app written in Swift, I recently got the following warning in Xcode:

`Could not create compact unwind for [symbol]: stack subl instruction is too different from dwarf stack size`

How can I fix or silence it?

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to [this discussion](https://github.com/facebook/zstd/issues/969), I found the suggestion of setting the following linker flag:

```
LDFLAGS="-Wl,-no_compact_unwind"
```

Where does this go in Xcode? Select the target where you're getting the warning, and search for "linker" so that you can set `Other Linker Flags` to `-Wl,-no_compact_unwind`:

[image: Screenshot of "Other Linker Flags" set to "-Wl,-no_compact_unwind"]

(This corresponds to the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` settings in the `.pbxproj` file.)

This silenced the warning for me. If anyone knows of a better way to fix or address the underlying issue, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Warning! For me this makes exceptions not being catchable but my application (macOS) terminates with
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type CoupledField::Exception:
This was years before with intel and is now with M1 when using clang.